# Reload current screen when an exception occurs

Tags: flutter

I have a screen on which a user can input some number which he then confirms. Confirming makes an API call. This call can fail. When it fails I show an `AlertDialog` with `showDialog`. 
What I want is, that when the user dismisses the dialog the screen refreshes/reloads. The input data should be erased (and there are some other effects which should be reset too).

I'm not sure what the best way to achieve this is.

```
  void _handleError(e) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builder) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(e.toString()),
          content: Text('Some content'),
        );
      },
    );
    // I'm guessing I should do something here?
  }

  // This is the handler for the confirm buttons `onPressed` field. 
  void _pay(context) {
    double amount = double.parse(textFieldController.text);

    apiClient
        .createInvoice(amount)
        .then((Map<String, dynamic> invoice) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return Pay(invoice);
        }),
      );
    }).catchError(handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showDialog()` function returns a [`Future`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Future/Future.html) when it gets dismissed. So you can chain a `then()` call to the `showDialog()` and perform your clean up there.

```
void _handleError(e) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext builder) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(e.toString()),
        content: Text('Some content'),
      );
    },
  ).then((_){
    //do your clean up
    _inputTextController.text = '';
  });
}
```